# Grunt doesn't start debug mode

Tags: selenium, jasmine, gruntjs

I'm using Grunt to run my tests and it works well when I use it in normal mode "run local_test", but when I try to run it in debug mode "debug local_test" it shos me this Error:

```
    Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::59699
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
        at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
        at listen (net.js:1298:10)
        at net.js:1408:9
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

does anyone have an idea what could cause this behavior and how I could fix it?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The port is in use, you might need to kill a runaway process and try again or change the port number.

Comment: I tried to kill the process but I get the error "Process not found". The thing is, everytime I try to run a debug mode, I get a different port number!

Comment: Could just be two different services as part of your build trying to use the same port?